# change size of electron (Atom Shell) WindowBrowser from command line or external program

Tags: command-line, electron

I want to control the window size of an electron (atom-shell) WindowBrowser object from an external program. I know within the electron app code I can use the WindowBrowser.SetSize(w, h) method, but I need events in a different (non-electron) program to trigger this behavior. Is there a good way to do this? If Electron cannot do this, is there another desktop application framework or method that could accommodate this?

Currently, my hope is to set the WindowBrowser ID in a file, then read that file from the external program and send a command line string that tells the electron app to SetSize of the WindowBrowser referenced using its ID. I am totally new to Electron, and I have no idea if this will work or how to do it.

Comment: There are Node modules you can use in Electron to create an HTTP server and listen on a port. It is possible for you to create a simple local RESTful API using these modules that you can run from your main.js. You could create a GET call to query for window id's and a POST call to update the window size via the SetSize method you described. Would something like that work for you here?